# Is 288×288 dp the same as 288×288 px for Android splash screens? How can I create an Android vector drawable splash screen in Inkscape?

Tags: android

I want to create a vector drawable splash screen.

I have created a 192x192 px circle in a 288x288 px document in Inkscape. I have no background in the document, only the 192x192 px circle. I want to use the svg file in Android Studio to create an xml file for my splash screen.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

> Splash screen dimensions
> App icon without an icon background: this must be 288×288 dp and fit within a circle 192 dp in diameter.

I'm not sure if I use the correct width and height in Inkscape because the dimensions are in px and not in dp.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzypp.jpg)

Can I use these dimensions in Inkscape or is it necessary to change them for my Android splash screen?